# Supabase join returning 1 object instead of list of objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, supabase

I am trying to query my `posts` table for a post, which contains the user's `user_id` and I want to join it with the `profiles` table using the `user_id`.

post table schema: `(post_id: uuid, created_at: timestamptz, image_url: text, user_id: uuid, num_likes: integer, description: text)` My foreign key relation is set up on supabase with this table and profiles for the `user_id`.

profiles table schema: `(user_name: text, first_name: text, last_name: text, is_premium: boolean, user_id: uuid, num_posts: smallint, num_followers: integer, num_following: integer)`

when trying to query the tables with:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("posts")
      .select(
        `post_id, created_at, image_url, user_id, num_likes, description, profiles ( user_id, user_name, first_name, last_name, num_followers, num_following, num_posts, is_premium )`
      )
      .limit(1)
      .single();
```

I recieve no errors and I correctly receive a user's profile information, but the `data.profiles` is expected to be an array. However, it is not returning an array, it just returns a single object for `data.profiles`.

sample of what the query is returning:

```
Object {
  "created_at": "2023-07-29T15:54:53.849017+00:00",
  "description": "This is a description",
  "image_url": "NULL",
  "num_likes": 3,
  "post_id": "e0392738-5085-4026-9446-56e4bde69fee",
  "profiles": Object {
    "first_name": "John",
    "is_premium": true,
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "num_followers": 0,
    "num_following": 0,
    "num_posts": 0,
    "user_id": "108a1e53-1df6-4baf-a4ca-f0c445f085d2",
    "user_name": "User123",
  },
  "user_id": "108a1e53-1df6-4baf-a4ca-f0c445f085d2",
}
```

but this is the expected type:

```
data: {
    post_id: any;
    created_at: any;
    image_url: any;
    user_id: any;
    num_likes: any;
    description: any;
    profiles: {
        user_id: any;
        user_name: any;
        first_name: any;
        last_name: any;
        num_followers: any;
        num_following: any;
        num_posts: any;
        is_premium: any;
    }[];
}
```

More Context:
Here is the unedited function that calls from supabase:

```
export const getNextPost = createAsyncThunk(
  "getNextPost",
  async (payload: {
    lastPostCreatedAt: string;
  }): Promise<(postsTableRow & { profiles: profilesTableRow }) | null> => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("posts")
      .select(
        `post_id, created_at, image_url, user_id, num_likes, description, profiles ( user_id, user_name, first_name, last_name, num_followers, num_following, num_posts, is_premium )`
      )
      .order("created_at", { ascending: false })
      .lt("created_at", payload.lastPostCreatedAt)
      .limit(1)
      .single();
    if (error?.code === "PGRST116") return null;
    if (error) console.warn(error);
    console.log("DATA:", data);
    return data as postsTableRow & { profiles: profilesTableRow };
  }
);
```

if I change the return type from: `Promise<(postsTableRow & { profiles: profilesTableRow }) | null>`
to `Promise<(postsTableRow & { profiles: profilesTableRow[] }) | null>`

The compiler warning goes away but it still returns a `profilesTableRow` not the expected `profilesTableRow[]`

Comment: Did you try to remove the `.single()` method? Because it returns `data` as a single object instead of an array of objects.

Comment: @Emre yes it still expects data.profiles to be an array

Comment: I want it to return a single object, but I'm confused as to why its returning something else from what it expects

Comment: Could you share more example for your question (you can edit it)? Actually it works properly.

Comment: @Emre I added the full unedited function that I'm using to query supabase. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much better solution:
It seems like generating types for the supabase client, using the supabase cli seems to have also fixed this issue. Supabase docs: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/rest/generating-types

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround casting the result as an `unknown` and then to the correct type fixes the error. In my case I did `data?.profiles as unknown as profilesTableRow` so that `data.profiles` is no longer expected to be an array (even though its already not an array).

Seems like it's just a supabase bug